# Lifted corner shadows extending to the side

Tags: css-transforms, css

A website I'm working on needs to use a certain shadow effect for some panels.
I have found the desired CSS shadow on the web but I have noticed it has some problems - when the target div is very tall, the shadow pops out behind it on its sides.

I discovered the shadow is built from two, solid colour, rectangular objects that cast the shadow. They hide behind the div at an angle which creates that 'curly', sheet of paper-like shadow effect. This angle also makes them pop out when used with a very tall div block.

I'm not very good with CSS so I don't know how to fix that. I've tried limiting the rectangles max-height property, but that makes them too short to leave any shadow below the div.
Is there a way to make the boxes stick to the bottom of the div and never extend around its sides?

This is the shadow I used:

```
.shadow {
position: relative;
}
.shadow:before, .shadow:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    bottom: 12px;
    left: 7px;
    width: 50%;
    top: 80%;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.6);
     box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.6);
     -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(-4deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
      transform: rotate(-4deg);
}
.shadow:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(4deg);
    transform: rotate(4deg);
    right: 7px;
    left: auto;
}
```

You can see an example in this fiddle, the first div shows the shadow working properly, the second one shows the problem: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/e6yh07pd/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the `top` property on the pseudo elements and give a fixed height to them. You can also give a `max-height` value to pseudo elements to ensures they don't overflow the div when it is short :

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/e6yh07pd/2/)**

```
.box {
    background-color: #3a6fa9;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    border-radius: 4px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}
.box-tall {
    width: 500px;
    height: 2000px;
}
.shadow {
    position: relative;
}
.shadow:before, .shadow:after {
    z-index: -1;
    position: absolute;
    content:"";
    bottom: 12px;
    height:100px;
    max-height:10%;
    left: 7px;
    width: 50%;
    max-width: 300px;
    background: #777;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.6);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.6);
    box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.6);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
    transform: rotate(-4deg);
}
.shadow:after {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(4deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(4deg);
    transform: rotate(4deg);
    right: 7px;
    left: auto;
}
```

Comment: would that also make the shadow stay consistent? I noticed that when the blocks become really huge the shadows move closer to the middle

edit: yeah, just checked. this also fixed the positioning of the shadows for me. hence I'll accept your answer.

Comment: @kacpr the shadow will be conssistent even for huge divs.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `top: 80%;`, you can just set a small height, such as `height: 20px;`:

```
.shadow:before, .shadow:after {
z-index: -1;
position: absolute;
content: "";
bottom: 12px;
left: 7px;
width: 50%;
height: 20px;
/* top: 80%; */
max-width: 300px;
background: #777;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.6);
-moz-box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.6);
box-shadow: 0 15px 10px rgba(119, 119, 119, 0.6);
-webkit-transform: rotate(-4deg);
-moz-transform: rotate(-4deg);
-o-transform: rotate(-4deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(-4deg);
transform: rotate(-4deg);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

your fiddle updated: http://jsfiddle.net/e6yh07pd/3/

problem was the

```
top:80%;
```

value you have. can't understand why you used it... isteed remove it and just add a height fixed (px) for your after and before

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate answer... guess we all posted same time :(. I was NOT the first